# Attaching Database Problem?

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2000

I get a database from sql 2005, then i try to attach the database in sql 2000, it showing error as "could not find row in sysindexes for database id 8 object id 1 index id 1 run dbcc checktable on sysindexes"

Is possible to attach the database, or any other way to attach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot attach a database from a newer version of SQL Server in an old system. This has never worked, and probably will never work.

The only way to move a database from 2005 to 2000 is scripting: script out the structure in 2005 and re-create it in 2000, and script out the data (if needed) into INSERT INTO statements and run those on 2000.

Marc